# Error with led Blinking (avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state)

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new with Arduino and I made something very basic and I don't know why it is not working . I placed the positive led in pin 13 and the negative in GND and wrote this code :

```
#define LED 13
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

I verified if it 's connected to Arduino Uno and when I upload the code I have this errors :

```
Sketch uses 924 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\COM4"
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Sometimes IDE has problems ? What I did wrong ?

Comment: Genuine Arduino or a cheap Chinese clone?

Comment: I bought a kit from keyestudio

Comment: It's this a bad company ?

Comment: Starting from https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=54796.msg2032153#msg2032153 someone seems to have found a solution.

Comment: so you didn't use a resistor and shorted the pin to ground with the LED? btw. the Uno has on board LED on pin 13 and Blink example does the same as your sketch

Comment: Yes. I followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnPPoetX0uw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [avrdude ser\_open() can't set com-state](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55301/avrdude-ser-open-cant-set-com-state)

Comment: Dp you have some older version of Uno, because R3 doesn't have a resistor on pin 13.

Comment: I have the same question on any sketch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a problem with LED blinking (although there seems a resistor missing for your led), but with uploading a sketch.

Hard test: switch off your computer, remove USB cable, switch on computer, check the COM port appearing when connecting the Arduino via USB cable. Then start IDE and try upload again.

Eventually something else was blocking the COM port.