# OEM Arduino UNO not seen by COM port

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, ch340

Arduino UNO R3

My error code:
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\.\COM3"
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

This has been mentioned several times before here in the Stack.  I have been through several of them and followed the steps to delete/reinstall the CH340G Serial driver, change cables, and changed the USB port selection on the computer, all without success.  The computer will 'see' the UNO.

I use Windows 11.  I also learned that the card is a counterfeit from LAFVINTECH.COM.
At the moment, I have no answers.  I've tried everything I know of except taking it to the gun range.

Comment: Did you try turning the computer off then on again?

Comment: Have you seen this Q+A? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55301/avrdude-ser-open-cant-set-com-state

Comment: Did you assign USB on the Windows computer?  Then Arduino IDE should be able to find the hardware when uploading the Sketch. This works for me.

Comment: Here are the answers to the above comments.

Comment: Did you try turning the computer off then on again? – 
VE7JRO

YES

Have you seen this Q+A? arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55301/… – 
VE7JRO

YES.  

Did you assign USB on the Windows computer? Then Arduino IDE should be able to find the hardware when uploading the Sketch. This works for me. – 
John

The Computer automatically assigns a COM port to the connection.  There are three USB ports on the front of the tower.  They are COM 3, COM 4, and COM5.  The computer has the correct Driver and then responds with a visible tie between card and PC.

Comment: The Computer automatically assigns a COM port to the connection.   ....  Normally in Arduino IDE you can pull down and change this,

Comment: I have more information that may be helpful - I connected an ATMEGA328P_U (call this one "A") to TWO different PCs and it worked fine.  I then connected an ATMEGA328P_U_TH (Call this one "B") to both PCs and it did not 'see' the card in the proper way.    "A" com port responded by adding 'Arduuino Uno' to the COM port number.  "B" did not.